# Linux on Lenovo Ideapad 5 pro Gen 8 (14APH8)

Tags: kernel, multiple-monitors, xorg, display

I have the 14" model with 7840HS and 32GB RAM (4GB of which is allocated to the 780M).
Under Windows the graphics work without any problems, but under Linux I always have problems with the internal display.
I have already tried various distros (Ubuntu, openSUSE (Gnome), Manjaro (KDE), Mint Cinnamon Edge), and it's always more or less the same problem.

The system can be started and the login also works, but sooner or later there are the first graphics errors or the screen becomes 3/4 to 100% monochrome. If only one part turns gray / black, the rest can be used "normally", however sometimes the entire display is destroyed. I have sometimes managed to log out or go into standby using key combinations. Then the display is fine again and I can log in again. When I connect an external monitor, the problem sometimes goes away, sometimes it comes back, but always only on the internal display, the external monitor works fine.
Under Ubuntu I have tried Wayland and Xorg, but nothing changes.

I have also tried different kernels. Manjaro is on 6.5 anyway, and under Ubuntu I have tried different kernels with the mainline installer - without success. I also tried new MESA drivers under Ubuntu, but nothing changes either.

Does anyone else have this problem? Maybe someone has an idea how to solve it?

[image: screen sample 1]

[image: screen sample 2]

Answer (score 0):

Try Ubuntu Unity (23.10). Everything has been working well for the past 3 months. In your case, it seems to be a problem with Wayland.